# How to get a stack trace object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stack, stack-trace

I need to get a stack trace object in Ruby; not to print it, just to get it to do some recording and dumping for later analysis. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use [Kernel.caller](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) for this. The same method is used when generating stack traces for exceptions.

From the docs:

```
def a(skip)
  caller(skip)
end
def b(skip)
  a(skip)
end
def c(skip)
  b(skip)
end
c(0) #=> ["prog:2:in `a'", "prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:10"]
c(1) #=> ["prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:11"]
c(2) #=> ["prog:8:in `c'", "prog:12"]
c(3) #=> ["prog:13"]
```

Answer (score 48):

Try

```
Thread.current.backtrace.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 12):

Try [error.backtrace](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Exception.html#M000924):

```
# Returns any backtrace associated with the exception.  
# The backtrace is an array of strings, each containing either ``filename:lineNo: in `method’’’ or ``filename:lineNo.’‘

def a
  raise "boom"
end

def b
  a()
end

begin
  b()
rescue => detail
  print detail.backtrace.join("\n")
end
```

produces:

```
prog.rb:2:in `a'
prog.rb:6:in `b'
prog.rb:10
```

Comment: I presume I'll have to throw an exception just to get the stack trace.

Comment: @J. Pablo  Seems so. Post here if you find a way to get it directly.

Comment: Sven nailed it with Kernel.caller.

Answer (score 11):

For Ruby 2.0+, you can use [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations). It is essentially the same as [`Kernel#caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) (covered in [Sven Koschnicke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829269/1157054)), except that instead of returning an array of strings, it returns an array of [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) objects. `Thread::Backtrace::Location` provides methods such as [`path`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-path), [`lineno`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-lineno), and [`base_label`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-base_label), which may be useful when you need access to specific details about the stack trace, and not just a raw string.

From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations):

> ### caller_locations(start=1, length=nil) → array or nil
>
> ### caller_locations(range) → array or nil
>
> Returns the current execution stack—an array containing backtrace
>   location objects.
>
> See [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) for more information.
>
> The optional start parameter determines the number of initial stack
>   entries to omit from the top of the stack.
>
> A second optional `length` parameter can be used to limit how many
>   entries are returned from the stack.
>
> Returns `nil` if `start` is greater than the size of current execution
>   stack.
>
> Optionally you can pass a range, which will return an array containing
>   the entries within the specified range.

Usage example:

```
def a
  caller_locations(0)
end
def b
  a
end
def c
  b
end

c.map(&:base_label)
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "<main>"]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Thread.current.backtrace
```

This will give you an array which contains all the lines that you may get in any normal backtrace.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own if you want as well. As demonstrated in *Eloquent Ruby* by Russ Olsen:

```
# define a proc to use that will handle your trace 
proc_object = proc do |event, file, line, id, binding, klass| 
  puts "#{event} in #{file}/#{line} #{id} #{klass}"
end 

# tell Ruby to use your proc on traceable events
set_trace_func(proc_object)
```