# how to get/traceback method calls stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If `method A` is called by other methods,

Is there any way to know which function call it at run time.

I can grep the whole project to list all the possible calling path,

But if I can know it at run time, it'll be more helpful.

How can I get it by embedded something in `method A`

for example, the calling flow maybe

```
C() -> B() -> A()

H()-> G()-> B()-> A()
```

I wanna know the recent 3,or 5 method calls,

I want to trace the flow in my controllers and helpers in Rails project
But I require the tracer and it showed me.

```
Routing Error

undefined method `on' for Tracer:Class

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Here's my code

```
      Tracer.on
  def generate_nonexisted_book(price)

   ~~~
  end
  Tracer.off
```

Comment: Why not raise an exception in `method A`?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122233

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby has one **stdlib** called [`Tracer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html). I would demonstrate it with a small example s below :

```
require 'tracer'

Tracer.on
def a;end
def b; a ; end
def c; b ; end
c
Tracer.off
```

Let me now run the code :

```
(arup~>test)$ ruby -v c.rb
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]
#0:c.rb:4::-: def a;end
#0:c.rb:5::-: def b; a ; end
#0:c.rb:6::-: def c; b ; end
#0:c.rb:7::-: c
#0:c.rb:6:Object:>: def c; b ; end
#0:c.rb:6:Object:-: def c; b ; end
#0:c.rb:5:Object:>: def b; a ; end
#0:c.rb:5:Object:-: def b; a ; end
#0:c.rb:4:Object:>: def a;end
#0:c.rb:4:Object:<: def a;end
#0:c.rb:5:Object:<: def b; a ; end
#0:c.rb:6:Object:<: def c; b ; end
#0:c.rb:8::-: Tracer.off
(arup~>test)$
```

Description of some symbolic notations here came in the output:

- **+>+** - call a Ruby method
- **-** - execute code on a new line
- **+<+**  - return from a Ruby method

Comment: Can I use it in my rails project, thanks~ I got errors.

Comment: @poc Did you use `require 'tracer'` ?

Comment: This is hard to find THING, very useful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the methods `Kernel.caller` or `Kernel.caller_locations` can help you:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations