# Triggering Pry binding based on contents of stacktrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I want to start a Pry session in a function, but due to some meta-programming in the project I'm now working on, Pry gets triggered in a lot of contexts that I'm not interested in. How can I trigger pry based on the stack-trace of the program's current execution?

Something like,

```
binding.pry if stacktrace.include? "function_name"
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @theTinMan I imagine `stacktrace` isn't defined. So he'd get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'stacktrace' for main:Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ruby 2.0+, you can use [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations) to get the current stack trace of the program.

From [the docs for `Kernel#caller_locations`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations):

> ### caller_locations(start=1, length=nil) → array or nil
>
> ### source caller_locations(range) → array or nil
>
> Returns the current execution stack—an array containing backtrace
>   location objects.
>
> See [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) for more information.

So as we can see from the documentation, this method returns an array of [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) objects, which you can use to determine whether or not to call `binding.pry`. `Thread::Backtrace::Location` provides a method called [`base_label`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-base_label), which returns the name of the method in the current position in the stack. You can use this to check whether the current stack trace runs through a method with a specific name.

Usage example:

```
def a
  caller_locations(0)
end
def b
  a
end
def c
  b
end

c.map(&:base_label)
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "<main>"]
```

So in your case, you'd use it like this:

```
binding.pry if caller_locations.map(&:base_label).include? function_name
```

---

If you're using an older version of Ruby (< 2.0), [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations) isn't available, and you'll have to use [`Kernel#caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) instead:

> ### caller(start=1, length=nil) → array or nil
>
> ### caller(range) → array or nil
>
> Returns the current execution stack—an array containing strings in the
>   form file:line or file:line: in `method'.
>
> The optional start parameter determines the number of initial stack
>   entries to omit from the top of the stack.
>
> A second optional length parameter can be used to limit how many
>   entries are returned from the stack.
>
> Returns nil if start is greater than the size of current execution
>   stack.
>
> Optionally you can pass a range, which will return an array containing
>   the entries within the specified range.
>
> ```
> def a(skip)
>   caller(skip)
> end
> def b(skip)
>   a(skip)
> end
> def c(skip)
>   b(skip)
> end
> c(0)   #=> ["prog:2:in `a'", "prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:10:in `<main>'"]
> c(1)   #=> ["prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:11:in `<main>'"]
> c(2)   #=> ["prog:8:in `c'", "prog:12:in `<main>'"]
> c(3)   #=> ["prog:13:in `<main>'"]
> c(4)   #=> []
> c(5)   #=> nil
> ```

You'll notice that the only difference between `Kernel#caller_locations` and `Kernel#caller` is that `Kernel#caller` returns an array of strings, not an array of `Thread::Backtrace::Location` objects. This means that you'll have to use something like regular expressions to match the method name, instead of just using [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) as we did with `Kernel#caller_locations`. In your case:

```
binding.pry if caller.any?{|stack_entry| stack_entry =~ /in `#{function_name}'$/}
```

For more information on getting stack traces in Ruby, see [how to get a stack trace object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3829157/1157054)

Comment: I ended up going with `binding.pry if caller.any?{|stack_entry| stack_entry =~ /[actual name of function]/}` because I could hardcode it (I'm just debugging). What is the purpose of the `$` symbol? I'm guess the 'extra' stuff is to allow for string interpolation inside of the regex?

Comment: @AndrewLngdn Notice how all the strings returned by `caller` are in the form ```"file:line: in `method'"```? Well, ``/in `#{function_name}'$/`` matches all strings that end with ``in `method'"``, specifically. ([Example / Full Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lG9cY2/1)) It's a bit more restrictive than just `/function_name/`, which matches the function name anywhere in the string, even in somewhere like the file name. Interpolation is done with `#{expression}`, the other characters are just part of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
binding.pry if caller.any?{|fn_name| fn_name.include?('function_name')}
```

Ref: [How to get a stack trace object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829157/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-object-in-ruby)