# Determine current queue from job

Tags: ruby, resque

I am on my way implementing some logging of resque activity using the resque hooks, e.g.:

```
def before_perform_log_start(*args)
  logger.info("Job #{self.to_s} started on queue #{queue_name}") # pseudo implementation
end
```

Now I want to include the queue on which the job is *actually* running. The naive approach would be to simply read the `@queue` instance variable, since we usually set that to indicate the jobs queue. However, any caller
can override the queue using `enqueue_to`:

```
Resque.enqueue_to('foobar', MyJob)
```

So my question is: **Can I determine the queue from which the job was actually pulled?**

In the stacktrace I can see that my job's `perform` method is called by an instance of [Resque::Job](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/resque/Resque/Job), which has an accessor for the queue. However, I see no way to obtain that job instance.

Comment: How did you get the stacktrace? By raising an exception?

Comment: [Using Kernel.caller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3829269/968531)